# Reset button works before submission but not after form submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

The following code works before I have clicked submit on form. So if I fill the fields before submission, and click Reset it works great.

```
<input type="reset" class="advanced-reset-btn" id="advancedResetButton" name="advancedResetButton" value="Reset" />
```

But after submission when I click this work, nothing happens. It doesn't reset the fields as it should
Any suggestions of how I should clear the form after submission onclick?

UPDATED

```
<form id="advancedSearchOrder" name="advancedSearchForm" value="advancedSearch" action="" class=" search line" method="GET" >
<span class="advancedSearchFormlabel">Order Id</span>
      <%= text_area_tag('filters[order_id]',filter_params['order_id'],:rows=>10) %>
...
...
...
<input type="submit" class="advanced-search-btn" id="advancedSearchButton" name="advancedSearchButton" value="Search"/>
<input type="reset" class="advanced-reset-btn" id="advancedResetButton" name="advancedResetButton" value="Reset" />
```

Comment: That line of code looks good. I created a simple example locally, and it worked fine. We'll probably need to see more code -- maybe the view and controller. On a hunch, I will say this: When you submit the form, the form is probably returned to the user pre-populated with the data the user entered. If this is the case, then clicking reset after the form has been submitted will result in different behavior than clicking it before the form is submitted. It will reset the form back to the user's submitted values, not to blank values.

Comment: @MichaelVenable You may be onto something...I will post the basic snipped of the view. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Yep. Looked over your code and I'm pretty sure that's what is happening. I'll create an actual stack overflow answer.

Answer (score 4):

The RESET input type resets the form back to the state it was in when the page was loaded, not back to an empty form. After submitting the form, the form is pre-populated with the submitted data. Resetting the form will reset it back to this pre-populated state.

You can test this by doing the following.

1. Enter ABC in a field and submit the form. The page reloads and the form is pre-populated with ABC.
2. Change the field to ABCDEF. Click RESET. The form resets to ABC.

This is the normal behavior of RESET and people familiar with RESET buttons will expect it to behave like this. If you want to erase all fields on the form, you will probably have to use javascript similar to Amar's answer. Another option is to clear the values in the controller so that a new, empty form is sent to the client after each form submission.

Comment: I am going to try something like this - $("#form_id").find("input[type=text], textarea").val(""), and let you know if it works....I had an idea of what was happening, and your explanation cleared any doubts I had.

Comment: This has no effect after submitting form either...What have I done wrong?
    <input type="reset" class="advanced-reset-btn" id="advancedResetButton" name="advancedResetButton" value="Reset" onclick='$("#advancedSearchOrder").find("input:text,textarea").val("")' />

Comment: Did you find an answer?  Can you accept one or post the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

The same button:

```
<input class='advanced-reset-btn'>Reset</input>
```

And in your javascript file:

```
$('.advanced-reset-btn').click(function() { $('#your-form')[0].reset() })
```

Comment: It works before I submitted the form...But after I have submitted the form the reset button doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: So, are you submiting your form via javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery or javascript to reset form on click
`$('#form_id')[0].reset();` or manually rest  value like this
or `$("#form_id").find("input[type=text], textarea").val("")`

Comment: Actually this works before I submitted the form...But after I have submitted the form the reset button doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: If you are submiting form with AJAX then on response you can reset may be successful response.

Answer (score 1):

The jquery val() function works on the property of the element. Try to erase the attribute.

$('form input').attr("value", "");